# How does the backwards pipeline (i.e. "<|") really work?

Tags: f#, pipeline

I need help understanding how "<|" behaves for the following code:

```
Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number ->

    let actual = transform number

    let expected = "FizzBuzz"
    expected = actual
```

The documentation says the following:

> Passes the result of the expression on the right side to the function
>   on left side (backward pipe operator).

**fiveAndThrees is a NOT a function but instead a value and it's on the left side of the operator.**

I interpret the above definition as:

Take an input called "number" and feed it into the "transform" function. However, if we're passing the result of the expression on the right side to the function on the left side, then when and how does the input (i.e. number) actually get initialized?

I just don't see it.

The full test is the following:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``FizzBuzz.transform returns FizzBuzz`` () =
    let fiveAndThrees = Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map ((*) (3 * 5)) 
                                          |> Arb.fromGen

    Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number ->

        let actual = transform number

        let expected = "FizzBuzz"
        expected = actual
```

The function to be tested is the following:

```
let transform number =  
    match number % 3, number % 5 with 
    | 0, 0 -> "FizzBuzz" 
    | _, 0 -> "Buzz" 
    | 0, _ -> "Fizz" 
    | _ -> number.ToString()
```

Comment: See http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/01/ad-hoc-arbitraries-now-with-pipes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<|` is an operator which binds less tightly than function application, so

```
Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees <| fun number -> ...
```

is parsed as

```
(Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees) <| fun number -> ...
```

[Prop.forAll](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/blob/5edec4286c223f7620de69120932050d78b182ee/src/FsCheck/Prop.fs#L22) takes two parameters, an `Arbitrary<T>` and a function `T -> Testable` so `Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees` is a function to which the right-hand side is passed.

Comment: Thanks Lee. But if the right side (i.e. expression) gets executed first, then how does the input (i.e. number) on the expression get initialized?

Comment: @ScottNimrod - The expression on the right just happens to be a function so it's just the same as as `Prop.forAll fiveAndThrees (fun number -> ..)`. I assume the use of `<|` is just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Right, my most-common use of the `<|` operator is when I don't want to wrap the stuff on the right in extra parens. Such as `raise <| CustomException(msg)` vs `raise (CustomException(msg))`. In this case, there was a multi-line lambda expression, which is a little awkward to wrap in parens.